# Unable to set Azure Devops Branch as Default

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to set a branch in ADO as default. According to the MS Guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops
there should be an option to set a branch as default. However, I don't appear to have that option, see image.

I currently have a branch set to default, and I would like to remove the status from default and assign the branch 'main' as the default. Can someone let me know how to do that and why I'm not able to see the option.

[image]

I don't appear to be able to navigate to Git Repository permissions tabe. Nearest I can see is:

[image]

Comment: Click on "Security" on your screenshot, it's next to "Policies". Then check to see if you can change **Edit policies** permission. If every permission is gray, you don't have enough permissions. Contact your Project Administrators to assign **Edit policies** permission to your account. Or you can ask him to set your **Manage permissions** to Allow for Git repositories. Then you can change repo permissions yourself. See more info from [Set Git repository permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Edit policies permission:

> Note
>
> Changing the default branch requires you to have Edit policies
> permission. For more information, see Set Git repository permissions.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shamrai. I'm not sure how to get to the same page you showed in your screenshot. I have updated the question showing the closest that I can get to what you described with our ADO

Comment: @Patterson check `project settings`->`Repositories`->`Security`. I updated my screenshot.

Comment: going to try your suggestion now. I will let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: I don't have the permissions. I will have to request the permissions from our Administrators. Can you let me know what are the advantage / disadvantage of setting a branch to default? Or should I say is there anything that I will be prevented from doing by not having a Branch set to default? This is so I can answer the administrator when he asks why I need the Edit policies permission. Thanks

Comment: @Patterson, The default branch is the first branch that Git will check out on a fresh clone. Also, pull requests target this branch by default. If you use code search, it only indexes files in the default branch of your Git repositories by default.